# iphone UISearchBar Done button always enabled

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uisearchbar, first-responder

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UISearchBar`. I have replaced the Search Button by a Done button.

However, when one taps on the searchbar, the Done button is initially `disabled`. This occurs until one enters any character.

What I want to do is to have this Done button always `enabled`, such that if i tap on it i can inmediately dismiss the keyboard.

Any help? it would be highly appreciated.

I have on my `UIViewController`

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar  
{   
    return YES;  
}  

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}  

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  
{  
    if (searchBar.text.length == 0)  
    {  
        //[self fixOrientation];  
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];  
    }   
    else  
    {  
        NSLog(@"typed");  
    }  
}  


-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar  
{  
    NSLog(@"began");  // this executes as soon as i tap on the searchbar, so I'm guessing this is the place to put whatever solution is available  
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nowadays `UISearchBar` conforms to `UITextInputTraits`. You can simply set:

```
searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
```

**WARNING:** While this compiles for iOS 7.0, it will **crash** at runtime. It only works for >=7.1.

The docs are not clear on this one, as only since 7.1, the `UISearchBar` implements the `UITextInputTraits` protocol, but it is not noted since which iOS version the protocol is adopted.

Comment: beautiful & simple! was coming back to this old question since i'm moving some oooooold apps to 64bits and forgot the solution for a specific use case

Answer (score 30):

You can get around this by looping around the subviews in the UISearchBar until you find the text field. Its then just a matter of setting "enablesReturnKeyAutomatically" to NO. Incidentally the following code also is useful for setting the keyboard type.

```
  // loop around subviews of UISearchBar
  for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchBar subviews]) {    
    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {    
      @try {
        // set style of keyboard
        [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

        // always force return key to be enabled
        [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
      }
      @catch (NSException * e) {        
        // ignore exception
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: is this really that difficult for this one simple stupid thing?

Comment: Last time I checked, yes, unfortunately it is.

Comment: Is the try/catch really necessary?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.  Please consider the category I posted.

Comment: As stated, this doesn't work with newer SDK versions.  Reason: This only checks subviews, not subviews of subviews, and the view hiearchy changed at some point between SDK/iOS 6 and 8.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore, so I made my own category that does seem to work:

```
@implementation UISearchBar (enabler)

- (void) alwaysEnableSearch {
    // loop around subviews of UISearchBar
    NSMutableSet *viewsToCheck = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[self subviews]];
    while ([viewsToCheck count] > 0) {
        UIView *searchBarSubview = [viewsToCheck anyObject];
        [viewsToCheck addObjectsFromArray:searchBarSubview.subviews];
        [viewsToCheck removeObject:searchBarSubview];
        if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            @try {
                // always force return key to be enabled
                [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                // ignore exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works too (at least on ios 9. not sure about the other):

if ([self.searchBar respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"searchField")]) {
        UITextField *searchTextField = ((UITextField*)[self.searchBar valueForKey:@"searchField"]);
        searchTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO; }

Answer (score 6):

Simple and easy solution for iOS 10 on XCode 8.3.3, although it took some time to figure it out :)

```
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar! {
    didSet {
        searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
    }
}
```

Changes Search to Done. Enables Done without having to type anything in the search field. After that -> searchBar.resignFirstResponder() like so:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: :) Did u figure it out eventually? :) There will always be someone that can make use of it. Glad to help, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 8 and above you can use

```
[self.searchBar setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[self.searchBar setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
```

Comment: it's working fine for me ,i just resign the keyboard when user click on Done button .So, this work fine for me

Answer (score 3):

**Set *enablesReturnKeyAutomatically* to false**

> enablesReturnKeyAutomatically

```
searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
```

Answer (score 2):

This code display Search Button if you have empty string:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [itemSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;
    for (UIView *subView in self.itemSearchBar.subviews)
    {
        for (UIView *sndSubView in subView.subviews)
        {
            if ([sndSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)sndSubView;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    searchBarTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is more likely to break again if the view hierarchy changes.  Recommend using a style like Gujamin's answer or a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Maps app, for example, it seems the pattern should be to have a cancel button near the textfield to get rid of the keyboard. With that said, one suggestion might be to have a custom `UIButton` placed right in that corner that looks just like the Done button.

Kind of a hacky solution...

Hope this helps!

Comment: mmmmmjm, not to convinced on that one (placing a button on top of that corner). I believe I saw once on the web how it was done but i haven't been able to find it again

Comment: @AndyDunn, maaaan, after a looooong time I realized that your solution actually is the proper one! I apologize for not having it tried when you posted. Sorry big time. I always appreciate the time other put into helping others here

Comment: Yep, it's a pattern that suits `UISearchDisplayController`-like search. Check iBooks, there's no _Cancel_ button there.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way and tricky is just put a blank when beginning editing search

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    //Add a blank character to hack search button enable
    searchBar.text = @" ";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension for Swift:

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var textField: UITextField? {
        return getTextField(inViews: subviews)
    }

    private func getTextField(inViews views: [UIView]?) -> UITextField? {
        guard let views = views else { return nil }

        for view in views {
            if let textField = (view as? UITextField) ?? getTextField(inViews: view.subviews) {
                return textField
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
searchBar.textField?.returnKeyType = .Done
searchBar.textField?.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
```