# UISearchBar with InputView

Tags: iphone, keyboard, inputview

I'm making custom keyboard for my app and it's working fine with UITextField. But UISearchBar don't support inputView

```
- (UIView *)inputView {
    if(self.keyboard==nil)
    {
        self.keyboard=[[[MMKeyboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"MMKeyboard" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    }
    NSLog(@"HERE");
    return self.keyboard.view;

}
```

How to replace with my custom UITextField in UISearchBar or how to implement inputView in UISearchBar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved like following

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MMKeyboard.h"

@interface MMSBar : UISearchBar {
    MMKeyboard* keyboard;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)MMKeyboard* keyboard;

@end




- (void)layoutSubviews {

    if(self.keyboard==nil)
    {
        self.keyboard=[[[MMKeyboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"MMKeyboard" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    }


    UITextView *searchField;
    NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
    for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
        if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            [searchField setInputView:keyboard.view];
        }
    }

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Will this method have no problems with Apple's review process?

Comment: there is no problem for my app.

Answer (score 2):

As this code is doing but you instead change the `inputView`:

```
// loop around subviews of UISearchBar
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchBar subviews]) {    
if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {    
  @try {
    // set style of keyboard
    [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

    // always force return key to be enabled
    [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
  }
  @catch (NSException * e) {        
    // ignore exception
  }
 }
}
```

See this post for more details:

[iphone UISearchBar Done button always enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728338/iphone-uisearchbar-done-button-always-enabled)