# Elegant way to swap keyboard for UIDatePicker in UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I know about this way [UISearchBar with InputView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769999/uisearchbar-with-inputview)

But I want to know if there is a "proper" way to do this at all? A better way than what appears to be a hack above, and there is obviously no guarantee that that will work in future versions of the iOS SDK.

I have a search bar, with a segmented control (scopes) and on one of the scopes I want to display a date picker instead of the keyboard. The `inputView` property is not accessible for a standard UISearchBar, so is there some other way of doing this?

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in 2 Points,
First Track the selected Scope
Secondly, Whenever your desired scope is selected then Resign the Keyboard and show the Picker.
Maybe this code will help you.

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope{
    // Track the Scope Selection    
    selectedSearchType = selectedScope ;
}


- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

   if(selectedSearchType=="Scope_which_will_expose_picker"){
     // Show Picker Here
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
   }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! :) I'll try this out today and see how it goes.

Comment: oh man its so much more complicated than you could ever imagine... but I'm figuring it out. You can have the answer, because its on the right track.